# Cytoscape.js cxttap event : Right click not working on macBook trackpad

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am running into a weird issue.

`Cytoscape.js` right click works when I right click using an externally attached mouse (bluetooth / USB), but does not work when I tap on the right-side of the trackpad on MacBook.The tap on macBook works ok for all other applications.

I am running  this on MacBook pro with Ventura 13.3.1 (a)

Is there an compatibility issue between MacOs tap events and `CytoScape.js`?
Any of following work for "mouse right click" but does not work for MacBook right side tap.

```
cy.on("cxttap", "node", (evt) => {
                    console.log("right click detected:");
                });
```

Or

```
 cy.elements().bind("cxttap", (event) => {
                    console.log("right click detected:");
                });
```